# Syntax for comparing type?

Tags: c#

I need to check the datatype of a datareader's columns:

```
Type type = dataTable.Columns[i].DataType;
if (type.Equals(System.Decimal))
{
    //...
}
```

However, the line `if (type.Equals(System.Decimal))` is not correct. What's the correct syntax?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, you could also use the `is` keyword: `if (type is System.Decimal)`.  Keep in mind that `is` checks assignability, not strict type equality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost have it right. Just change it to:

```
if (type.Equals(typeof(System.Decimal)))
```

Though a better way of expressing it would be:

```
if (type == typeof(System.Decimal))
```

and if you add a `using System;` to the top of your file, you can make it:

```
if (type == typeof(Decimal))
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `typeof`:

```
  if (type == typeof(Decimal)) {...}
```

note that `Equals` is not required and `==` is more *readable*.

Answer (score 1):

No need for the `type` variable;

```
if(dataTable.Columns[i].GetType().Equals(typeof(decimal)))
{
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do

```
if (dataTable.Columns[i] is System.Decimal)
{
    //...
}
```

Its a simplified type comparator

Comment: Take care with this though. `if (instanceOfClassThatImplementsISomething.GetType() is typeof(ISomething))` will be true, whereas `if (instanceOfClassThatImplementsISomething.GetType() == typeof(ISomething))` will be false.

Answer (score 0):

You can use typeof operator to check the type of DataColumn type.

```
if(dataTable.Columns[i].DataType== typeof(System.Decimal))
{
  //Your code
}
```